# How to get Tabulator (or any data table) to connect to RSS Feed

Tags: rss, tabulator

I am trying to get Tabulator (or any database) to connect to RSS feed. Tried using ajax, but cannot get to work. Tried to connect to a JSON feed, still no luck.
Maybe the ajax settings need to be customized. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-       tables/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="dist\css\1tabulator.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>`

<style>
body {
    background-color: rgb(224, 214, 214);
    color: black;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="example-table"></div>

<script>
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {

  ajaxURL: "https://www.jsonfeed.org/feed.json",
  //ajaxConfig: "GET",
  //ajaxContentType:"json",

height:"311px",
layout:"fitColumns",
placeholder: "Placeholder",
index:"id",
columns:[
  {title:"id", field: "id", hozAlign:"center", width: "12pt"},
  {title:"NewsTime", field:"title", hozAlign:"center", width: "12pt"},
  ],
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the JSON returned from that is not in a format parsable by Tabulator. it is expecting an array of objects and is getting back one object.

The good news is there is a callback to handle this. Looking at the response from that request, it looks like the data array sits on the `items` property of the returned object.

We can use the `ajaxResponse` callback to tell tabulator where to look for the data in the returned object:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL: "https://www.jsonfeed.org/feed.json",
    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        return response.items;  //return the array on the items prop of the response  
    },
});
```